# zeromq - bytearray (from .net server) to string in java

Tags: c#, java, zeromq

I'm working on a project that uses both .net and java, using zeromq to communicate between them.

I can connect to the .net server, however when I try to convert the byte array to a string strange things happen. In the eclipse debugger I can see the string, and its length. When I click on the string its value changes to being only the first letter, and the length changes to 1. In the eclipse console when I try to copy and paste the output I only get the first letter. I also tried running it in NetBeans and get the same issue.

I thought it might be due to Endianness, so have tired both
BIG_ENDIAN
LITTLE_ENDIAN

Anyone know how I an get the full string, and not just the first letter?

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;

class local_thr
{
private static final String ENDPOINT = "tcp://127.0.0.1:8000";
static String[]  myargs={ENDPOINT, "1000", "100"};  
  public static void main (String [] args)  {

  args = myargs;     

  ZMQ.Context ctx = ZMQ.context (1);
  ZMQ.Socket s = ctx.socket (ZMQ.SUB);

  s.subscribe("".getBytes());
  s.connect (ENDPOINT);

  while(true){
      byte [] data = s.recv (0);


     ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
      buf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

      byte[] bytes = new byte[buf.remaining()];
      buf.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

          String quote;
          quote = new String(bytes);

          String myQuote;
          myQuote = new String();
          System.out.println (quote);
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 char suggests that the data is being encoded as little-endian UTF-16 and decoded as nul-terminated (could be expecting single-byte, could be expecting UTF-8).

Make sure you are familiar with encodings, and ensure that both ends of the pipe are using the **same** encoding.

The java string(byte[]) constructor uses the default system charset; I would start by investigating how to read UTF-16 from java. Or maybe use UTF-8 from both ends. Using a default charset is never robust.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have included my older attempts, where I specified both UTF8 (which the server is sending) and still got the same result. I also tried UTF16 but got a Chinese looking string.

Comment: @Magick did you use the same at. Both? To be honest, I'd focus on gettimg the same **bytes** between servers; then: it is purely an encoding issue at each end.

Comment: Thanks again Marc, you put me on the right path. It was an encoding problem. Turns out the correct encoding was UTF-16LE.

Comment: @Magick there is no single "correct" here - it is only correct as long as both ends use the same; but if you mean the java needed to read it as UTF-16LE because that was what was being written - then indeed: that is exactly what I deduced (from the symptom) in the first few words of the answer :p

Comment: I have used UTF-8 encoded JSON and MSGPACK formats to handle serialising messages between different architectures. Using an explicit cross-platform serialisation is a best practice and just a darn good idea.

Comment: @MichaelDillon likewise (although I tend towards protobuf) - but if (as per this case) you aren't encoding output correctly all bets are already off ;p